# ARCore object becomes dark on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, arcore

I'm making iOS AR-app with Flutter and ARCore. But, its object becomes dark.
I want you to help solve this problem.
I'm using [ar_flutter_plugin](https://pub.dev/documentation/ar_flutter_plugin/latest/index.html)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ybl2N.png)